# Applying several patterns to `Split`

Tags: pattern-matching

Please consider the following:

```
Split[data, patterns &]
patterns=Not[#=="a"]&&Not[#=="b"]&&...&&Not[#=="blabla"];
```

How can I define `patterns` without typing `&&Not[#=="char"]` for every single pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add some syntactic sugar to do that relatively easily. For example, define a head for that:

```
ClearAll[SplitPattern];
SplitPattern /: Split[expr_, SplitPattern[pt_]] :=
   Split[expr, MatchQ[#, pt] &];
```

And use this as follows:

```
lst = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "blabla", "e", "f"}
Split[lst,SplitPattern[Except["a"|"b"|"blabla"]]]

(*  {{a},{b},{c,d,blabla},{e,f}} *)
```

The performance may not be that great, but I guess the question was more about convenience.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you really want to use set of different dividers, in that case, you can simply test using a function that checks whether the current element is a member of your set of deviders:

```
 dividers = {3, 4, 5}
 Split[Range@10, ! MemberQ[dividers, #] &]
```

To answer your litteral question, your `patterns` is basically `And` taken over a range of structurally identical terms that are functions of a list of dividers, so you could use `Map` and `Apply`

```
patterns= Function[t, And @@ (Not[t == #] & /@ {"a", "b", "blabla"})]
```

Then you can use

```
lst = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "blabla", "e", "f"}
Split[lst,patterns]
```

> ```
> {{"a"}, {"b"}, {"c", "d", "blabla"}, {"e", "f"}}
> ```

In a similar fasion, if you just wanted to combine a seriues of different test you could use `And@@{test1[#],test2[#],test3[#]}&`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I like your approach better from the perspective of comprehension. However, LeonidShifrins approach is faster.

Comment: @John One of the reasons why my code might be faster is that the `patterns` function here does not short-circuit: even when the very first pattern matches, it still goes on evaluating all others.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a temporary function which evaluates to `False` for your target strings and `True` otherwise.

```
splitAt[data_, x_] := Module[{f},
  (f[#, _] = False) & /@ x;
  f[__] = True;
  Split[data, f]]

lst = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "blabla", "e", "f"} ;
splitAt[lst, {"a", "b", "blabla"}]

(* {{"a"}, {"b"}, {"c", "d", "blabla"}, {"e", "f"}} *)
```